# Limit usage of $(document).ready(function() { })

Tags: jquery, html

How can I check that my document only has one instance of `$(document).ready(function()`?

If it's included more than one time, can I somehow remove duplicate instances (similar to PHP's `require_once();` function)?

Comment: just as a side note: it's perfectly fine to have multiple `$(document).ready` functions, they will be called in the order they were added.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: They aren't always called in order: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7279 - this only happens if you bind to the ready event.

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying that the exact same code could be added more than once?

If so, I suppose you could set a global property indicating if the code inside has already run, then test for that property inside the `ready()` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       // check a flag to see if this has been called yet
    if( !window.thisCodeHasRun ) {
           // set the flag to show this has been called
        window.thisCodeHasRun = true;

        /* run your code */
    }
});
```

It would be better to take care of this on the server side, but if you must do it client side, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use bind and unbind:

```
  $(document).bind("ready",function(){
    console.log("zero");
  });

  $(document).bind("ready",function(){
    console.log("one");
  });

  // get rid of previous ready events
  $(document).unbind("ready");

  $(document).bind("ready",function(){
    console.log("two");
  });
```

In the above, the first and second ready events will never fire because unbind has been called. So you will get "two" in the console.

Comment: The ready event code doesn't always run in order, so this wouldn't work as you expect: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7279